# How do I pass input="file" data between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a file upload button, where once a file is selected, the user is directed to another page with a form to fill in extra data before submitting.

Is this possible? To pass the input value over to another page? I noticed that the "value" of the form item is not the true value (i.e. prefixed with "C:\fakepath\"), so a simple setValue() on the form will probably not work.

If it makes any difference, I am using angular and ui-router. And when I say change page, I really mean change state.

Comment: you can't. allowing this would allow anyone to specify the path for ANY file on a user's system. e.g. an incredibly massive security problem. upload the file on one form, stuff it somewhere safe on the system, and then pull it out when the second form is submitted.

Comment: @MarcB -- Since OP is working within a SPA, you could probably just store the file data in a service on input change, and then fetch from that service. (or would that be lost?)

Comment: technically you _could_ but you would have to use an iframe and use [window.postmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), specifying the file object as a [Transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable)

Comment: Use a variable and store the value of the `HTMLInputElement.files` property. Done.

Comment: I guessed as much. Didn't think the "direct" approach would have worked for the same reasoning you gave. There must be a workaround that someone has come up with that doesn't affect security. Worst case, I can try to combine the two pages in one and simple keep one or the other in a hidden div at any time...

Comment: @Vohuman No, the precise file path is not accessible (let alone for storage in a variable) for security reasons.

Comment: @Terry One doesn't use the value property of the file input. What OP needs is the `files` property which returns a `FileList` object. It's a SPA application and the variable can be used in other states.

Comment: you can convert it to a hidden input or two to pass the file meta and file data, but you can't keep the file input populated between loads.

Comment: @Travis Kaufman that's all new to me. Based on your wording though it seems like you don't think it'd be a good idea?

Comment: I think that @Vohuman's solution(s) is/are the best. If it's a single-page app you can save the uploaded file as a variable and pass it along to the next controller route

Comment: @Vohuman huh, interesting. I'm assuming then that you can set the files property manually on the other form then?

Comment: You can read the file in a blob using the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I'll take a look at the API. A quick skim doesn't seem to show an example of uploading the file once read, but I can probably figure it out.

Comment: [Blob upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015555/pass-blob-through-ajax-to-generate-a-file) - it a jquery example but will also work with angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `File` object from the `HTMLInputElement.files` as a parameter to the state: `$state.go('form', {'file': file})`.

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0tm5hLu/1/) to demonstrate this solution.
The first state prompts the user to select a file, then redirects them to a second state passing the file as a parameter. In this example the file name is just printed out but you could easily read the file as well.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the form as a modal pop-up instead:

```js
  $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $("#file").change(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
  });
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Put your form here, for example.</p>
</div>

<input type="file" id="file" />
```