# Video stream to canvas to image using JavaScript for Project Oxford

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, azure-cognitive-services

I've been able to use Project Oxford, specifically the Emotions API by manually asking a user to upload pictures. However, I'm now looking to do this using a video stream (the webpage shows a live video stream from their webcam and the user can take a snapshot of the stream and then choose to have the emotions API run on that image, which will then run the API and show the scores in a dialogue window - this is the part which I am currently stuck with).

Below I've written the HTML and JavaScript code which sets up the video stream on the webpage and then allows the user to take a snapshot, which then converts the canvas to an image.

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <img id="file" src = "" alt="Emotions">
    <!--input type="file" id="file" name="filename"-->
    <button id="btn">Click here</button>

<script>

    // Put event listeners into place
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = { "video": true },
            errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
            };

        // Put video listeners into place
        if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }

        // Trigger photo take
        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
                            var dataURL = document.getElementById("canvas");
                            if (dataURL.getContext){
                                var ctx = dataURL.getContext("2d");
                                var link = document.createElement('a');
                                link.download = "test.png";
                                var myImage = link.href = dataURL.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                                link.click();
                            }
                            var imageElement = document.getElementById("file");
                            imageElement.src = myImage;
                            //document.getElementById("file").src = dataURL;
                     $('#btn').click(function () {
                            //var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];


                        $.ajax({
                                url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize",
                                beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
                                    // Request headers
                                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "my-key");
                                },
                                type: "POST",
                                data: imageElement,
                                processData: false
                            })
                            .done(function(data) {
                                JSON.stringify(data);
                                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            })
                            .fail(function(error) {
                                //alert(error.getAllResponseHeaders());
                                alert("Error");
                            });
                        });
        });
    }, false);

</script>
```

I'm not able to get the API running on the image after it's been converted as a canvas. After reading around, I believe this has something to do with the file extension that's given to the image after it's been converted as a canvas (there is none), as the API only allows for image file types. I believe this might be where the problem lies and any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: [send your canvas as a blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711715/phpjs-how-to-do-fileuploads-in-html-form-as-content-type-multipart-via-js/34713226#34713226), give it a filename, the API should accept it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment @Kaiido. I've tried the following however I'm still not being able to convert the blob to a jpeg:

`canvas.toBlob(function(blob){                              
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);       
      newImg.onload = function(){
              URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
              };
                                    
      newImg.src = url;
}, "image/jpeg", 0.95);`

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean? yes the blobURL you've created from the blob is a jpeg file. It's only in your browser memory but still it is. What you need is to send the blob to your API's server, don't send the blobURL, no one cares about it apart yor browser in your actual session :-). For this use a `FormData` object, as demonstrated in the linked answer. Also note that `canvas.toBlob` is still not widely supported, or with variations in the implementations, it is still recommended to do the dataURI to blob conversion manually.

Comment: Thanks for your comment again @Kaiido. I appreciate your help! I am trying to make sense of this as I'm totally new with JavaScript and blobs. I saw the example you linked me to however I'm not sure how that relates to my code as I'm not using PHP to inject? for example, what would I write in the URL part of my form variable as I have no PHP file (i.e. `url = 'http://example.com/upload.php`)?

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: replace your ajax call with the one in the answer, the Project Oxford API do handle the server-side. so `url = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize"`. But you may need to tweak a little bit the function so you can also send your credentials (`xhr.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "my-key");`)

Comment: Thanks! This makes much more sense now :) Also, would I need an xhr object to define the `"Content-Type"` as `"application/octet-stream"` also?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using to upload the picture to a backend API, which then use the .NET SDK after adding some business logic.
It is not the exact same scenario but the Javascript code might help you:

```
var url = 'Home/upload';

var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', imgData);

var imgData = canvas.msToBlob('image/jpeg');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
.done(function (response) {
    loading.style.display = "none";

    if (response.error != "") {
        result.innerText = response.error;
    }
    else {
        result.innerHTML = response.result;
    }
})
.fail(function (response) {
    alert('Error : ' + response.error);
})
.complete(function (response) {
    restartButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
});
```

The following thread helped me: [Pass Blob through ajax to generate a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015555/pass-blob-through-ajax-to-generate-a-file)