# Uploading a zip file using POST in Javascript fails silently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jszip

I am working on a web application (using JQuery version 2.2.4) that allows users to submit images and data to our server. When users decide to upload their submissions, my code should generate a zip file using the JSZip library and upload it to our server using POST. After some searching here on StackExchange, I came up with this code:

```
var zip = new JSZip();   // Create the object representing the zip file

// ...Add the data and images

console.log('Generating compressed archive...');
zip.generateAsync({
    compression: 'DEFLATE',
    type: 'blob'
}).then(function(zc) {// Function called when the generation is complete
    console.log('Compression complete!');
    // Create file object to upload
    var fileObj = new File([zc], fileName);
    console.log('File object created:', fileObj);
    $.post('http://myurl/submit', {
    data: fileObj,
    }).done(function() {
        console.log('Ajax post successful.');
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Ajax post failed. Status:', textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
});
```

My code prints the *File object created* message, the file object itself looks OK, but then I get nothing else. A silent failure. The POST call does not even appear in the Net panel for Firebug.

After more searching, I also tried to add this code beforehand:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    console.log('Ajax post failed. Event:', event);
    console.log('Ajax settings:', settings);
    console.log(thrownError);
});
```

But that doesn't get triggered. There's clearly some error I am making in setting up the callbacks for errors - what could I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to get the upload to work creating a FormData object and sticking my file into it. Here is the code:

```
var zip = new JSZip();   // Create the object representing the zip file

// ...Add the data and images

console.log('Generating compressed archive...');
zip.generateAsync({
    compression: 'DEFLATE',
    type: 'blob'
}).then(function(zc) {// Function called when the generation is complete
    console.log('Compression complete!');
    // Create file object to upload
    var fileObj = new File([zc], fileName);
    console.log('File object created:', fileObj);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fileName', fileName);
    fd.append('file', fileObj);
    fd.append('mimeType', 'application/zip');
    // POST Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://myurl/submit',
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    }).done(function() {
        console.log('Ajax post successful.');
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Ajax post failed. Status:', textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
});
```

This was inspired by the other StackExchange answers linked to by David Duponchel.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't see any `POST` because your data object doesn't contain only string values (I get a `POST` if I use `{data: "content"}`).

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/19015673 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18254775, you need to add some parameters ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)):

```
$.post({
  url: "/test",
  data: fileObj,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false
})
```

Comment: With your modification I get an HTTP error 400 (Bad request).

Comment: The answers you linked to were very helpful in solving my problem! I created a new answer so that I can put up the code.