# Send data from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, blob, signature, data-transfer

i have a web-application for signing pdf-files. I can upload a pdf-file into the system and store it as blob-file in a mysql database. In the viewer i can view the pdf-file with this code:

```
<?php
require_once("../controller/upload_system_va.php");

$id = intval($_GET['did']);
$PDF = mysqli_fetch_array(get_fileContent($id));
$PDFdata = $PDF['doc_blob'];
?>

...
<div class="viewer">
    <object id="viewer" name="view" data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo $PDFdata ?>" type="application/pdf"></object>
</div>
...
```

By clicking a button the signing process will start. I use this library for signing: https://github.com/Communication-Systems-Group/pdfsign.js
This is the code for signing:

```
$('#sign_load_btn').click(function () {
    var data = document.getElementById("viewer").data;
    data = convertDataURIToBinary(data);
    pdfSigned = PDFSIGN.signpdf(data, certInput, document.getElementById('password').value);

    sendDataToPHP(pdfSigned);
})
```

`sendDataToPHP(pdfSigned)` should send the signed pdf data to php and php should store the data back in the database as blob so that the next user can sign the pdf-file in same way.
Here is my problem, i dont get valid blob-data in php. In JavaScript pdfSigned is an object and in PHP it is an array and i dont have ideas to handle the data and how to convert it to blob.

Greetz and sorry for my bad english

ilikefatcats

UPDATE!!

The code of convertDataURIToBinary() is:

```
function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
    var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
    return decodeBase64(base64);
}

function decodeBase64(input) {
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    var size = 0;

    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

    var uint8 = new Uint8Array(input.length);

    while (i < input.length) {

        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        uint8[size++] = (chr1 & 0xff);
        if (enc3 !== 64) {
            uint8[size++] = (chr2 & 0xff);
        }
        if (enc4 !== 64) {
            uint8[size++] = (chr3 & 0xff);
        }

    }
    return uint8.subarray(0, size);
}
```

This code is originaly from the library PDFsign i dont change something.

I had tried to implement the `sendDataToPHP()` Method in different ways.
example:

signing.js:

```
function sendDataToPHP(pdfSigned) {

    if (pdfSigned != 0) {
        alert("insert if: " + pdfSigned);
        $.post("viewer.php", {
            view: true,
            pdfdata: pdfSigned,
        },
            function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    alert("Dateiübergabe erfolgreich");
                } else {
                    alert("Dateiübergabe nicht erfolgreich");
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

upload_system_va.php:

```
function signedDoc_to_db() {
    $pdfdata = $_POST['pdfdata'];
    $did = 49;
    //$signed_file = base64_encode(serialize($pdfdata));
    $signed_file = base64_encode($pdfdata);

    $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=signshare", "root", "");

    if (!$dbcon) {
        die('<p>Fehler beim Verbinden mit der Datenbank!</p>');
    }

    $insert_signedFile = $dbcon->prepare(
        "UPDATE document SET placeholder = :pdfdata WHERE did = :did"
    );

    $insert_signedFile->bindParam(':pdfdata', $signed_file, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $insert_signedFile->bindParam(':did', $did);
    $insert_signedFile->execute();

}
```

The result in this way is: 
$signed_file is NULL
$pdfdata is an array with exactly 1000 entries of numbers. its look like:

```
a:1000{i:0;s:2:"37";i:1;s:2:"80";i:2;s:2:"68";i:3;s:2:"70";i:4;s:2:"45" ... ;i:998;s:3:"153";i:999;s:3:"244";}
```

I dont know how to handle this array.. is this my pdf-file? how to make it to a blob? I tried to parse it into json but then i just have a json file with numbers...

*edit: i found out that this array includes 1000 numbers from 0 to 255, maybe it helps...

An other attempt was to write this code in signing.js:

```
function sendDataToPHP3(pdfSigned) {

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fname', 'test.pdf');
    fd.append('data', pdfSigned);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload_system_va.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        view: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });       
}
```

but in this attempt I dont reach the file `upload_system_va.php` the file is in the same directory like signing.js. Maybe my url is wrong?

I send the boolean 'view' because this start my function 'signedDoc_to_db()' in upload_system_va.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['view'])) {
    signedDoc_to_db();
}
```

A third way I found in the web was to make a blob file before sending it to PHP:

```
function sendDataToPHP2(pdfSigned) {

    var base64str = encodeBase64(pdfSigned);
    var binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    var len = binary.length;
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
    var viewA = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        viewA[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var blob = new Blob([viewA], { type: "application/pdf" });

    if (pdfSigned != 0) {
        alert("insert if: " + blob);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/mythesis/src/controller/upload_system_va.php',
            data: blob,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            view: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Daten wurden verschickt");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but here is the same problem like in attempt 2: i dont reach th PHP-code.

My skills in JS are not pretty good, I never worked with this language before. Maybe this code can help, its the code from the pdfsign-library to download the file after signing and this work well:

```
function createPDFDownload(array, filename) {
    var a = window.document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([array], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
    a.download = filename;
    // Append anchor to body.
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    // Remove anchor from body
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

The array in the parameterlist is the pdfSigned file from above. Maybe this code can help me? I tried this one:

```
function sendDataToPHP(pdfSigned) {

    var blob = new Blob([pdfSigned], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    if (pdfSigned != 0) {
        $.post("viewer.php", {
            view: true,
            data: blob,
            contentType: 'application/pdf',
            processData: false
        },
            function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    alert("Dateiübergabe erfolgreich");
                } else {
                    alert("Dateiübergabe nicht erfolgreich");
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

but then i get following error-message in the console-log:

```
TypeError: 'slice' called on an object that does not implement interface Blob.
```

I hope my question is understanable and someone can helps me. When you need more informations, please ask.

Greetz and another sorry for my english,

ilikefatcats

Comment: What exactly does `convertDataURIToBinary` do? What exactly does `sendDataToPHP` do? We can't see code for either of those, so please provide it so we can understand how the data is processed and sent. Also please show the PHP code which receives it, and show what the data looks like (e.g. via a var_dump()). Just saying "it's an array", doesn't give us enough to go on when we a) don't know what exact is in there, b) don't know what it looked like before you sent it, and c) don't know what you expected it to look like. Not enough info yet to help you, please update the question.

Comment: Hello ADyson and thank you for the answer. I'm at work and will update the question soon. 2 weeks ago a had the same question with more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812052/store-pdf-object-data-from-js-as-blob-in-database-with-php   but nobody react to it so I thought to wirte the question another time smaller. There are not all answers to your questions but maybe it helps to understand the problem.

Comment: Ok. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015555/pass-blob-through-ajax-to-generate-a-file would help you, btw.